# On how to get a solution for a nonhomogeneous problem for the heat equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, intuition

Evans PDE book presents the following problem (page 87):

> Write down an explicit formula for a solution of 
>   $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
> u_t-\Delta u+cu=f &\text{ in }\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty) \\ 
>  u=g&\text{ on }\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\} 
> \end{matrix}\right.\tag{1}$$
>   where $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

In the text (page 51) was given a solution of

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
v_t-\Delta v=F &\text{ in }\mathbb{R}^n\times(0,\infty) \\ 
 v=G&\text{ on }\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\} 
\end{matrix}\right.\tag{2}$$

So, it's seems natural to try to reduce $(1)$ to $(2)$. This was done [here (page 10)](http://www.math.umn.edu/~robt/docs/evans_solutions.pdf).

**My question** (possibly elementary) **is:** If no one give us the answer, how can we discover that we should set $v(x,t)=u(x,t)e^{ct}$? What's the insight behind this choose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Since the general solution of $u_t+cu=0$ is $u(x,t)=C(x)e^{ct}$ , therefore let $v(x,t)=u(x,t)e^{ct}$ can solely eliminating the term $cu$ of the PDE.