# Evan PDE exercise 7 chapter 7

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde

[Exponential decay estimate for $(x,t) \in U_T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159668/exponential-decay-estimate-for-x-t-in-u-t)

I have question from the above mentioned problem:

I take $v=e^{\gamma t}u(x,t)$, then

$v_t= u_t e^{\gamma t}+ \gamma u e^{\gamma t}$

$\Delta v= e^{\gamma t} \Delta u+ 2 \gamma u_t+\gamma^2e^{\gamma t} u$

So, $v_t -\Delta v-(\gamma -c)v=-\gamma^2u e^{\gamma t}- \gamma u_te^{\gamma t}$.

I stuck here, how do I claim $v_t -\Delta v-(\gamma -c)v \geq 0$. I want to show this to apply maximum principle.

Can anyone suggest some hint to handle the last step?

Answer (score 3):

The Laplacian is only in terms of the spatial variables. In particular $\Delta v= e^{\gamma t}\Delta u$. This, together with your formula for $v_t$, gives
$$
v_t-\Delta v= -cue^{\gamma t} + \gamma e^{\gamma t} u= (\gamma-c)v.
$$
Therefore $v_t-\Delta v + (c-\gamma)v =0$. Since $c-\gamma\geq 0$, we can apply the weak maximum and minimum principles.